# UIAlertView lags, leaves dim effect, then causes the screen to flicker on iOS 6.1

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I haven't touched [this code](https://github.com/ipwnstuff/shodan/blob/master/shodan/Classes/View%20Controllers/MasterViewController.m#L214) in a while so I'm wondering if there are any obvious things that would cause the problem I'm running into.

I'm displaying a `UIAlertView` to the user after they perform a search query. This worked fine until I started testing on iOS 6.1 (or this particular iPad 2 I'm using for that matter). Now it acts as normal until **dismiss** the `UIAlertView` and then the screen stays dimmed for a few seconds.

This didn't seem like a problem, other than a bit of lag, until I noticed that I could still touch a table view in my app which causes flickering of the screen to occur.

The code is on my github: [ipwnstuff/shodan](https://github.com/ipwnstuff/shodan/blob/master/shodan/Classes/View%20Controllers/MasterViewController.m#L214)

Comment: My first guess would be that you are not dismissing it on the main thread, but rather in a background thread....  If not that, then if you could be more specific with which portion of the code that you have linked is causing the problem, we could better help.

Comment: I linked to line #214 as that's where I called `[alert show];` in the method that's giving me this behavior. I'm not exactly sure what's causing this problem hence why I posted a link to my code instead of an example.

Comment: Where are you dismissing it that is causing a problem though?  And are you dismissing it on the main thread?

Comment: Right, didn't see that in your first response. Yeah, I am calling it from a background thread. Is that not valid anymore?

Comment: Nope, all `UIKit` interactions (like those involving `UIAlertView` - notice the `UI` at the beginning of the class) need to be on the main thread.  It has always been that way, but you don't always see immediate problems if you do it the wrong way.

Comment: I see, thanks. If you'd summarize your comments I'll accept it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure that you are displaying (and dismissing if doing so programmatically) the alert on the main thread, along with all other interactions with `UIKit`.  The easiest way is to use a block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Display/dismiss your alert
});
```

Comment: This fixes my problem, but in turn locks up the keyboard. I need to refactor my code and work more on threading instead of using convenience methods like: `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething) withObject:self];`.

Comment: @Inafziger Thanx for your excellent solution, could you please explain what you mean by `Dismiss alert`? alerts are dismissing by user and in default cases we don't write code to `Dismiss` alerts. For example, in my case I use your code above to `Show` alert, so : `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Show alert
});`

Comment: @Malloc:  You are also able to programmatically dismiss `UIAlertView`'s as well, using `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`.  Most people don't need to use this method, however when you do, it needs to be done on the main thread as well.  The same method also needs to be used to display the alert, as you show in your comment.

Comment: Also, [NSThread mainThread] will return YES if it is called on the main thread. Handy for debugging.

Answer (score 7):

Using lnafziger's answer I showed the alertView on the main thread rather than dismissing it. Which fixed the problem too.

```
[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```